# Piece of advice for a SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

For my machine learning course, I have to find the SVD of the following matrix  $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 \\
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{11}{5} \\
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{11}{5} \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

I found that $\sigma_{1} = 4$ and $\sigma_{2} = 2$. With those information, I found that the V matrix equals V = 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \\
\frac{4}{5} & \frac{-3}{5} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Finally, I managed to compute $u_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0.5 \\
0.5 \\
0.5 \\
0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix} $ and $u_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
0.5 \\
0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

My question is the following: How can I compute $u_{3}$ and  $u_{4}$ in a mathematical way ( I found that $u_{3} = \begin{pmatrix}
-0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
0.5 \\
0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix} $ and $u_{4} =  \begin{pmatrix}
0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ could work)? Should I use the null space on A transpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U_{3}$ and $U_{4}$ aren't uniquely defined- any two orthogonal vectors in the null space of $A^{T}$ will do.  You could, for example, compute a basis for $N(A^{T})$, and then apply the Gram-Schmidt process to orthogonalize the basis.

Note that in multiplying out $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$, these last two columns of $U$ are multiplied by the corresponding singular values, which happen to be 0.  Thus they don't contribute anything to the product.

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for your answer that helped me a lot.